# Django ModelForm in Modal on Home Page

Tags: python, django, forms, bootstrap-modal, modelform

I have a form that is rendering on its own template page 'build-project-custom.html' in a Django Application. I'm trying to repeat the form as a pop-up modal on the home page. I keep getting the error:

> Parameter "field" should contain a valid Django BoundField.

I don't think I quite understand how ModelForm's work in the views or how they are populated in another class based view. I basically want a user to be able to submit this form on a modal on the home page. Help is greatly appreciated. I'm rather new to Python and Django so a simple explanation would be greatly appreciated.

buildproject/models.py

```
class CustomProjectBuildRequest(models.Model):
CUSTOM_PROJECT_CONTACT_METHOD = (
    ('Email', 'Email'),
    ('Call', 'Call'),
    ('Text', 'Text'),
)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name='First Name')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name='Last Name')
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=False, verbose_name='Email')
phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Phone')
created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Requested')
updated_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Updated')
project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Project Name')
project_description = models.TextField(null=False, verbose_name='Description')
preferred_contact_method = models.CharField(max_length=512, choices=CUSTOM_PROJECT_CONTACT_METHOD,
                                            verbose_name='Preferred Contact Method')

# Admin database comments for each project request created
customer_contacted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Customer Contacted')
customer_comments = models.TextField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Admin Comments')
```

buildproject/forms.py

```
class CustomProjectBuildRequest(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = CustomProjectBuildRequest
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'project_name', 'project_description',
              'preferred_contact_method']

class PMPIndex(ListView):
template_name = 'pmp/index.html'
model = Post
```

buildproject/views.py

```
def custom_project_build_request(request):
if request.method != 'POST':
    form = CustomProjectBuildRequest()
elif request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomProjectBuildRequest(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "Form successfully submitted")

return render(request, 'build-project-custom.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

Home Page Views.py

```
class PMPIndex(ListView):
template_name = 'pmp/index.html'
model = Post

def custom_project_build_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomProjectBuildRequest(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CustomProjectBuildRequest()
    return render(request, 'build-project-custom.html', {'form': form}))
```

Home Page Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="request-custom-project-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
 aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-
            {% include 'build-project-custom.html' %}
  </div>
  <div class=" modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why your model and form have same name `CustomProjectBuildRequest`?

Comment: I guess I should change that to CustomProjectBuildRequestForm

Comment: You have errors in your code. Did they happen during copy and paste?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the FormView to the class based view.

```
class PMPIndex(ListView, FormView):
template_name = 'pmp/index.html'
model = Post

form_class = CustomProjectBuildRequestForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(PMPIndex, self).form_valid(form)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
    context['lastThreePosts'] = Post.objects.order_by('-posted')[:3]
    return context

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.object = None
```